# How to wrap label with max-width

Tags: html, css, label, flexbox

I've got this code:

HTML:

```
<div class="propertyContainer">
    <div class="property">
        <label>This one is a very long label</label>
        <select></select>
    </div>
    <div class="property">
        <label>Short label</label>
        <select></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.propertyContainer{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex: 0 0 450px;
    min-height: 30px;
}
.property {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 30px;
}
label {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
select {
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

RESULT:

[image]

I've got the problem, when my label is to long, it doesn't wrap it. I tried to use a `max-width: 150px;` for my `label`, but than it just overlaps the other label without floating the container:

[image]

I have no idea how to fix this. I just would like to set a max-width an than wrap the label and float the conatiner so it should look like this:

[image]

I searched and tried a lot but at the moment I havn't got a solution. I also tried it with `word-wrap: break-word;`, but it also went wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: The issue is you're setting a height on `.property` and `label` so the text overflows that element when you try wrapping it. You need to allow elements to grow if you don't want this to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set `display: flex` on `property` and `flex: 1` on `select` and `label`

```css
.propertyContainer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 450px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.property {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 5px;
}
label,
select {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="propertyContainer">
  <div class="property">
    <label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minim</label>
    <select></select>
  </div>
  <div class="property">
    <label>Short label</label>
    <select></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to point out that the main issue the OP was facing was that they were setting a fixed height on various elements and you are not. Which allows the element to expand to fit the content.